# Change the index of an array to Topmost position in php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array say

```
$actual = array("orange", "banana", "apple", "raspberry", "mango","pineapple");
```

Now I want the "apple" value to hold the first index in the array such that it holds the first position and remaining values follow it as show below.

Desired array :

```
$output = array ("apple", "orange", "banana", "raspberry", "mango", "pineapple");
```

How can I achieve this ?

Thanks for reading !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$actual = array("orange", "banana", "apple", "raspberry", "mango","pineapple");
$apple = $actual[2];
unset($actual[2]);
array_unshift($actual, $apple);
```

Comment: Just a hint. `unset($actual[array_search("apple",$actual)]);`

Comment: Thank you that worked out :) 

@shankar --> yes bro, I have used array_search just to avoid hardcoding the value .
help is appreciated .

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($actual[0] != 'apple') {
        unset($actual[array_search('apple', $actual)]);
        array_unshift($actual, "apple");
}

print_r($actual);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$actual = array("orange", "banana", "apple", "raspberry", "mango","pineapple");
        for($i=0; $i<sizeof($actual); $i++)
        {
            if($actual[$i] == "apple")
            {
                for($j=$i; $j>=0; $j--)
                {
                    if($j != 0)
                    {
                        $el=$actual[$j];
                        $actual[$j]=$actual[$j-1];
                        $actual[$j-1]=$el;  
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        print_r($actual);
```