# How can i change an index of an array in php

Tags: php, arrays, indexing

How can i change an index of an array in php?
for example

```
$myArray = {"x","y","z","w"};
```

I want to change the index of myArray [2] to myArray ["two"]

Comment: You want to change the value or the key?

Comment: I want to change the key.

Comment: You can't change it, just assign the new key and remove the other. It'd be the same as chaning `$var1` to `$var2`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change the index of an array to Topmost position in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22909426/change-the-index-of-an-array-to-topmost-position-in-php)

Comment: http://xyproblem.info/ - What's the purpose? Why switch from indexed to associative? Why just one key? Or why not right in the declaration if it's just for one entry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `unset()` to achieve this:

```
$myArray = ["x","y","z","w"];
$myArray['two'] = $myArray[2];
unset($myArray[2]);
```